# Cannot fill an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS programming, but i want to create my own script to practice more, but I need some help. 
So, i have a simple array creation in the beginning of my script:

```
Var    
viewportHeight = $(window).height();
contentTop = [0, viewportHeight, viewportHeight*2, viewportHeight*3, viewportHeight*4];
```

And then in the middle of the code I need to have a function that triggers on window resize and refills the array with new values.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < contentTop.length; i++) {
    contentTop[i] = {
      viewportHeight * i
    };
  }
});
```

Something like this has to work in other programming languages, but doesn't work in JS, at least in my case. Is there a different way to do it?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? What is the specific error you're facing?

Comment: Just omit the curlies: `contentTop[i] = viewportHeight * i;`

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id in this line  contentTop[i]= 
   {viewportHeight * i};

Comment: Looks like you forgot to omit the curlies

Comment: You have to remember to omit curlies in all programming languages

Comment: It looks like this was the syntax problem, but still, it doesn't trigger, i have a watch set up to track contentTop changes, and it doesn't change on resize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reassign the `viewportHeight` variable when window size is changed and also remove the curly braces

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   viewportHeight = $(window).height();  // without this line the values are never changed
   for (i = 0; i < contentTop.length; i++) {
      contentTop[i] = viewportHeight * i;  // curly braces removed
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually works, finally i finished my project!

Answer (score 0):

Omit curlies and then try like - contentTop[i] = viewportHeight * i;